# Database reporting more space reserved than total size

Tags: sql-server

I have a database which has four data files and a log file. The data files are each around 5 GB, the log is about 1 GB. The database reports the total space reserved as around 21 GB, and of that 18 GB is in use. This information is corroborated by:

- Disk Usage Report
- Database Properties dialog (in Management Studio)
- `sp_spaceused`
- `sys.database_files`
- The data files on disk

However, the Disk Usage Report and `sp_spaceused` are both reporting that there is around 61 GB of data file space reserved, leaving around 43 GB as "unused" (i.e. not containing data). This should be impossible as the **total** space reserved is only 21 GB.

This phantom reserved space certainly isn't on the hard drive, so it must be a case of incorrect data somewhere in SQL Server. Where is it and how do I restore normality?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code behind `sp_spaceused`, it references a system table called `sys.allocation_units` which stores statistics about how big each object in the database is. In particular, the `total_pages` and `used_pages` columns relate to the reserved and used disk space reported by `sp_spaceused`. The following query can help to pinpoint which objects are reporting the excessive reserved space:

```
SELECT
    o.name,
    a.total_pages * 8 / 1024. AS 'Reserved_MB',
    a.used_pages * 8 / 1024. AS 'Used_MB'
FROM sys.allocation_units a
INNER JOIN sys.partitions p
    ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.all_objects o
    ON o.object_id = p.object_id
ORDER BY a.total_pages - a.used_pages DESC;
```

Once a table has (or some tables have) been identified, their statistics can be updated by running one of:

```
-- Update the whole current database
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(0);

-- Update the whole database
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(DATABASE_NAME);

-- Update a single table and its indexes
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(DATABASE_NAME, 'TABLE_NAME');

-- Update a single index within a table
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE(DATABASE_NAME, 'TABLE_NAME', 'INDEX_NAME');

-- Update the whole current database and run sp_spaceused
EXEC sp_spaceused @updateusage = 'true'
```

The report should now correctly report (or be closer to correctly reporting) the true reserved and used disk space for the database.

More information is available at MS Docs on [DBCC UPDATEUSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql) and [sp_spaceused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql).